# 18.04: After adding projector to touchscreen PC, mouse icon flicker and touch calibration lost

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, touchscreen

[image]Using Ubuntu 18.04 on system UDOO x86 with Intel graphics card.
Using my touch screen without connecting the external montior everything is just fine the touch screen is good and mouse cursor movement is smooth. 
As soon as i connect a second monitor i loose the touch calibration and also there is a lot of mouse flickering when the mouse is moved.
BTW my second monitor is a projector.
Projector resolution is 1920x1080p
Touchscreen primary is 1024x600
I am using extended display
Waiting for advice

Comment: Is the second display (the projector) mirroring the first, or is it extending the displayspace? Please test in both configurations, then come back here, click [edit], and post the results within your question. Also please note the original resolution and refresh rate used on the touchscreen, and the resolution and refresh of the projector.